# Problem with result of a sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql statement that repeat a record sevral time I don't know why!

This is my statement:

```
select   floor((a.created-c.created)*24)
      || ' HOURS ' ||
       mod(floor((a.created-c.created)*24*60),60)
     || ' MINUTES ' ,a.pkey as AssignedGroupResponseTime,a.pkey,d.newString as AssignedGroup

from
(
select g.created,g.issueid as groupid1, ji.pkey ,ci.newString
from   changegroup g
join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
where (g.created, ji.pkey) in (
select min(g.created) ,ji.pkey 
from   changegroup g
join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
join   priority pr on (pr.id = ji.priority)
where  ci.field = 'Group'
and  ci.oldString like 'Triage' 
and  p.pname = 'Change Management'
and pr.pname='P3'
and  ji.created between '01/03/2011' and  '16/08/2011'
group by ji.pkey
)) a
left join   (
select ji.created, ji.id as groupid2 ,ji.pkey ,ci.newString 
    from   jiraissue ji
    join   changegroup g on (g.issueid = ji.id)
    join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
    where  p.pname = 'Change Management'
    and ci.field = 'Group'
    and  ci.oldString like 'Triage' 
    and  ji.created between '01/03/2011' and  '16/08/2011' 
 ) b ON ( a.pkey = b.pkey)  
 left join (
    select g.created, g.issueid as groupid1 ,ji.pkey ,ci.newString
    from   changegroup g
    join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
     join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    where (g.created, ji.pkey) in (
    select min(g.created) ,ji.pkey
    from   changegroup g
    join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
    join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
    join   priority pr on (pr.id = ji.priority)
    where ci.field='assignee'
    and ci.newString is not NULL
    and  p.pname = 'Change Management'
    and pr.pname='P3'
    and ji.created between '01/03/2011' and  '16/08/2011'
    group by ji.pkey)) c
    ON (c.pkey = a.pkey) 
 left join (
    select g.created, g.issueid as groupid1 ,ji.pkey ,ci.newString
    from   changegroup g
    join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
    join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    where (g.created, ji.pkey) in (
    select min(g.created) ,ji.pkey 
    from   changegroup g
    join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
    join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
    join   priority pr on (pr.id = ji.priority)
    where ci.field='assigned group'
    and ci.newString is not NULL
    and  p.pname = 'Change Management'
    and pr.pname='P3'
    and  ji.created between '01/03/2011' and  '16/08/2011'
    group by ji.pkey)) d
     ON (d.pkey = c.pkey);
```

Comment: I suspect this question is getting closed

Comment: yes, poor documented question. you should dig yourself enough and after that create a question.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have duplicate keys on view b or c. 
You can run separately this views and see what is wrong(duplicate key values). 
In that view you have joins. Almost one join is made with a weak condition. That means you have duplicate matches for one condition.

Comment: +1 Duplicated rows are almost always the result of a botched join: a missing criterion which leads to a cartesian product.